# Detener lectura de JSON en node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, webservice, validación, try-catch

Estoy haciendo un Web Service en Node.js en donde tengo que hacer varias validaciones pero si una de esas validaciones da un error necesito que el Web Service siga corriendo pero deje de validar, como si fuera un Try... catch solo que no se si en mi caso se puede usar try...catch. AYUDA!

Este es el código ejemplo:

```
var number = "No soy un numero";
if(Number.IsInteger(number) == true){
  console.log("Soy un numero")
}else{
   new throw Exception("Se necesita un numero")
 //aqui no deberia de seguir ejecutando el codigo.
}

//No deberia imprimir esto.
console.log("Continua...")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estabas muy cerca pero tenías algunos errores de sintaxis:

```
var number = "No soy un numero";
if(Number.isInteger(number) == true){
  console.log("Soy un numero")
}else{
    throw new Error("Se necesita un numero")
 //aqui no deberia de seguir ejecutando el codigo.
}

//No deberia imprimir esto.
console.log("Continua...")
```

El primero es `isInteger` comienza con minúscula.

El segundo para ejecutar tu error debes usar `throw new Error` en  ese orden y con `Error` en vez de `Exception`

Y sobre tu pregunta si puedes usar try catch, si puedes.

Comment: Intente hacerlo asi pero sigue validando o sea, sigue imprimiendo el comentario "Continua..." :(

Comment: cómo lo estás ejecutando? fíjate en la salida de mi consola: https://ibb.co/nfV9QK

Comment: Sigo sin poder reproducir tu problema, en mi consola nunca veo lo que está después del if https://ibb.co/nntMPe

Comment: Ya ha funcionado!! Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Number.isInteger devuelve true o false por lo que no te hace falta la comprobación con true, por otro lado puedes usar el operador ternario como indico a continuación.

```
let number = "No soy un numero";
Number.isInteger(number)
  ? console.log("Soy un numero")
  : throw new Error("Se necesita un numero")
```

Comment: Por favor agrega una descripción de qué hace este código. Esta respuesta apareció en la cola de publicaciones de baja calidad. Lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta? - Escribe a lo mejor de tu habilidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)